# Meteor: is mongodb suitable for a whole application?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm new to the NoSQL world, and I just found [this article](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb).

I tried to understand what it is saying, but some things are not trivial to understand for me. I also noticed this article is a little bit old, so I want to know if it still applies, when the author saids that *you should never use MongoDB*.

So I want to know if he is right, so I should stop learning mateor.js? meteor is totally based in MongoDB. I'm really confused after read this article...

Comment: i don't understand why people downvote questions of new people who are confused instead of suggesting them good things. it is not necessary to take it personally and criticise the person who is bewildered into a new thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know is this is an answer or a long comment, but ...

No one can tell you if *"a hammer in an useful tool or not"*. The whole thing depends on *your* use case. To feed your reflexion, MongoDB do *not* have join, nor transactions. If you need them, it is *probably* not the right tool. If you *don't* need them, *maybe* it could be the right tool. Or, in the same spirit, if your application suits well with a traditional RDBMS, you don't need to switch to NoSQL. But if you reach the limits of the RDBMS (because you need very high performances, or scalability, or you are working with "big data") *probably* it is time to look at some alternatives.

Anyway, be warned: NoSQL is not a drop in replacement for RDBMS. It's a whole different thing to learn.

Answer (score 2):

The previous post by "Sylvain Leroux" has well explained you the things however to little add or emphasis few things you should know that

1. Mongo is not good for some specific cases but shine for others. you cannot treat it as a replacement of RDBMS and vice-versa as well. Its same like a needle and sword has their own benefits and you cannot use either one of them as a replacement for other.
2. Technically you don't have joins like in RDBMS but do we really need them.? Most of the cases NO, as we can Embed in the same collection and for few we can have separate collection and "Link" them.
3. People say there is no transaction in Mongo, it looks that we cannot achieve the transaction like behaviour in Mongo. Trust me, its not a limitation, its a feature. (May be in separate discussion I can tell why). to achieve the transaction like behaviour you can tweak your code so that its like "eventually consistent" when it comes to transaction. The best example you can refer here where user A transfer money to user B.
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Answer (score 1):

Any technology has its own pros & cons. If your article shows why MongoDB can not be used for that application, there are some other applications where MongoDB is one of best solutions.

http://www.netsolutionsindia.com/blog/what-is-mongodb/